# Moving columns of an HTML table containing cells that span multiple columns

Tags: linux, html, html-editor, table

I want to change the position of a few columns in a largish HTML table ([this one](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/commentary/libraries/version-history)).

What's a good editor for doing this? I've found https://truben.no/table/ but it doesn't support `colspan`s. The table editor plugin in Brackets doesn't seem to be able to do it either.

Comment: Which operating system? Must it be [tag:gratis], or do you ave a budget?

Comment: @Mawg. I'm on Linux. I wouldn't have paid for the program in this case, but if there's a good paid program, that would be interesting too.

Comment: I added the [tag:Linux] tag for your. It's your call as to whether to add the [tag:gratis] or even [tag:open-source] tag. The more info you give, the more likely a satisfactory answer. GIGO :-)  Good luck

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to working with large tables, I use a spreadsheet and export the csv, to an online table generator.

This makes editing, safe as the data can be restored if I mistake is made. Easy to save all my tables, and just in my opinion makes life so much easier.

I edited so many html, markdown tables online, or manually and it is a pain.

I use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables generally, or the wikipedia virtual editor.

Comment: Interesting! CSV AFAIK doesn't support cells spanning multiple columns though, so I suspect that this wouldn't work in my case.

Comment: Yes of course, it doesn't offer all the fine bells and whistles, but, it, serves as a safe redundant place, to format basic settings and then fine tune.